# Replacement for Indexing service on Windows 2012 server

Tags: asp-classic, connection-string, catalog, windows-search, indexing-service

Our company have 2 current website is hosted on a windows server 2003. The web sites are built in Classic ASP and use a MSIDXS provider to connect to a particular data source/indexing service catalogue (one for each website) and display the results of an SQL search based on a string parameter back onto the ASP page.

We are in the process of moving these websites across to a Windows server 2012, which no longer support indexing service:
[Confirmation on Microsoft website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee805985(v=vs.85).aspx)

As such our IT department has installed Windows Search via the Roles within the server management on the 2012 server (we can only FTP to the server for security reasons) but we can't find any information about how we can connect our ASP page to the windows search service, define where it should search in order to produce search results.

Has anybody else had this issue and resolved it?

Comment: So you haven't seen this? [Using SQL and AQS Approaches to Query the Index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff684395(v=vs.85).aspx), gives a VBScript example of how to talk to Windows Search using Windows Search SQL in [tag:ADODB].

Comment: Thanks @Lankymart I have managed to work out that I need to point my indexing options to the folder for my web site and then I have taken the ADO & VBScript code to create a record set but my page keeps timing out - despite extending the `Server.ScriptTimeout`